# What is the syntax for the SNMP trap configuration group policy?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy

I want to configure SNMP traps through group policy, but the trap configuration dialog is just a plain list of strings.

[image]

What do I have to enter here to configure the community name and trap server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to enter the name (or IP address) of the trap server. The community name is deduced from the order in which the community and the trap servers are defined in the GPO.